# Can two laptops on one wifi have different external IP's?

Tags: ip, wifi, wireless

Is there any way for two laptops that are connected to one wifi obtain different external IP address. What I mean is that when we go to site like ipchicken.com it will show different IP's for both of us. Because now we both see same IP.

Could this be achieved?

Comment: VPN would be one way.

Comment: Afaik it's possible, however the majority of ISPs don't permit multiple ip's to a modem/router. The alternate solution would be a router that has 2 network interfaces, then you can usually assign devices to each interface. As @Thilo says, VPN (or proxies) is probably the way you want to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should attach a switch to the modem, then connect both laptops and the router(wifi) to it. That way you can assign external IPs directly to the laptops. Then attach other devices such as PCs to the router as normal.

Source: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/40244-42-servers-external-address-router

This video may be of some use: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YFJOCJTkyI It explains the differences between a router, modem and switch and how to use them.

EDIT: Thilo is correct. You will need to request additional IPs from your ISP.

Comment: Only works, though, if that modem gives you more than one external IP.